# Want to make checkbox checked in Bootstrap Admin LTE theme using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I want to make checkbox checked while editing any entry in [Bootstrap Admin LTE theme](https://almsaeedstudio.com/) using AJAX and PHP.

[image]

[image]

I can get and display all other fields data like this: `$returnData['field']['field_name'];`

But not sure how to make the checkbox checked... I tried using:

`$returnData['checkbox']['checkbox_field_name'] = 'check';`

But it didn't work for me as I'm assuming its not the right way.

I would appreciate if someone can help on understanding the correct way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself :)

I google it a lot before posting the question on stackoverflow but didn't find anything so I'm sharing it here so it will be helpful for others like me.

You can do it like this:

```
if ($row->db_column == 1) {
    $returnData['check']['checkbox_field_name'] = 1;
}
```

Its necessary to use the **IF** condition because otherwise it will make the checkbox always checked.

So `$returnData['check']` was the right way to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('checkbox').prop("checked",true);
```

After your Ajax Callback.